# Regex match string followed by nothing or a string ending with a non-digit character

Tags: regex, rust

I need a pattern that will match the given string, or if the string has a prefix, it has at least to be followed by a non-digit character. For example, given "0.3.5":

```
0.3.5, matches
v0.3.5, matches
2021-version0.3.5, matches
10.3.5, does not match
v00.3.5, does not match
v0.3.5-M1, does not match
```

I have tried `(.*[^\d]|)0.3.5`, but it also matches "10.3.5". How can I write the regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Rust-specific

Based on the comment below, if lookarounds are unavailable, use this alternate approach:

```
^(?:.*\D)?0\.3\.5[^\s\d]*(?:\s|$)
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/B8jfQ7/3)

## Original solution

You may use this regex:

```
(?<!\d)0\.3\.5(?!\S*\d)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/B8jfQ7/1)

**RegEx Details**

- `(?<!\d)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have a digit before current position
- `0\.3\.5`: Match `0.3.5`
- `(?!\S*\d)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't another digit after 0 or more non-whitespace characters ahead of the current position

Comment: I am coding in Rust. And look-ahead and look-around is not supported in the crate that I'm using `regex`

Comment: ok try this: `^(?:.*\D)?0\.3\.5[^\s\d]*\s*$`

Comment: Yes, I will accept it once I test it in my code for all the patterns. Thanks. @anubhava